# Call Click Event Once After Element Appears?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery 1.6.2. I want to call a click event just for once when that element appears at page. This is my selector:

```
span[resizer='north'][title=''] :first-child"
```

This can work for triggering click event:

```
$("span[resizer='north'][title=''] :first-child").click();
```

How can I make it work only once or *after* that element appears on the page?

Comment: use the `off()` to unbind the click event

Comment: Is the element loaded via AJAX, or just in the DOM normally?

Comment: @VDesign `off()` is not part of jQuery 1.6.2?

Comment: correct use the `unbind()` instead

Comment: @j08691 there are some vm files and they are combined at one page. It is loaded within one of that vms.

Comment: @VDesign I am not binding a click event. I am calling event.

Comment: vm as in virtual machine?

Comment: You should mention how you add this element to the DOM and what do you mean by *make it to work only once*. Once and never again, even if the page is refreshed?

Comment: I mean I will call click event only once. Let's assume that there is a button. I will call click event of that button once. I mean I will programmatically click that button.

Comment: @kamaci Is the element being added to the page more than once? If you're adding the element programmatically, I guess I'm confused as to why you can't just do: `add element;click on element` then be done with it. Might help to stop being vague and tell us exactly what's happening with your code and the exact problem you're trying to solve, because it's not really clear right now.

Comment: So you mean you have a button that will trigger a click on `span[resizer='north'][title=''] :first-child` but you want that button to only trigger it once?

Answer (score 0):

Answer as per how I understand your last comment: *I mean I will call click event only once. Let's assume that there is a button. I will call click event of that button once. I mean I will programmatically click that button.*

```
$('button').click(function() {

    $('span[resizer='north'][title='']:first-child').click();
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `DOMNodeInserted` event to detect when new element is inserted dynamically.

```
var alreadyclicked = false; // variable to check that it will be clicked just once
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    if (!alreadyclicked){
        $("span[resizer='north'][title=''] :first-child").click();
        alreadyclicked = true;
    }
});
```

**Update**

The `DOMNodeInserted` event is deprecated along with other [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events). Some browsers support it, but looks like this won't last long.

You can use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead to keep track of changes in DOM

```
var alreadyclicked = false;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
            //if new nodes were added
            if( mutations[0].addedNodes.length && !alreadyclicked )
                $("span[resizer='north'][title=''] :first-child").click();
                alreadyclicked = true;

        });
observer.observe( document, { childList:true, subtree:true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom event, with a delegated handler attached using .one().

An event has 2 components, triggering and handling.  Don't focus on how many times it's triggered, focus on how many times it's handled.

```
$("document").one("myclick", "span[resizer='north'][title=''] :first-child", function(e) {
  do something...;
  $(this).click(); //if you actually need the "click"
});
$("span[resizer='north'][title=''] :first-child").trigger("myclick");
```

This example will mean it's "handled" one time.  The other answers on here can be used to ensure it's triggered when the element is added if it's after document ready.

You could also use a pub/sub which would make it even easier.  Then you just have to trigger your custom event from the ajax or whatever code that would add the element and not worry about specifically targeting the element.  Last line of code in the subscription would be to unsubscribe.